# ClassCastException when trying to make a class proxy

Tags: java, proxy

Why doesn't it work (specifically, the cast)? I thought a proxy extends the original class so it should go smoothly since casting to a superclass is always fine

```
public class BigDecimalUtils {
    /**
     * Compares two instances of <code>BigDecimal</code> ignoring scale
     * @return <code>true</code> if two decimals are equal, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public static boolean areEqual(BigDecimal firstDecimal, BigDecimal secondDecimal) {
        return firstDecimal.compareTo(secondDecimal) == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a <code>BigDecimal</code> proxy with an overriden <code>equals()</code> method that doesn't take scale into account
     * @param scaleAwareBigDecimal <code>BigDecimal</code> that needs to be proxied
     * @return new <code>BigDecimal</code> proxy instance
     */
    public static BigDecimal getScaleObliviousProxy(BigDecimal scaleAwareBigDecimal) {
        return (BigDecimal) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                scaleAwareBigDecimal.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                scaleAwareBigDecimal.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                (proxy, method, args) -> {
                    if (isEquals(method)) {
                        BigDecimal bigDecimalEqualsWasCalledOn = (BigDecimal) proxy;
                        BigDecimal bigDecimalPassedToEquals = (BigDecimal) args[0];
                        return areEqual(bigDecimalEqualsWasCalledOn, bigDecimalPassedToEquals);
                    } else {
                        return invokeAsUsual(proxy, method, args);
                    }
                });
    }

    private static boolean isEquals(Method method) {
        return method.getName().equals("equals");
    }

    private static Object invokeAsUsual(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return method.invoke(proxy, args);
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy1.$Proxy8 cannot be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal (jdk.proxy1.$Proxy8 is in module jdk.proxy1 of loader 'bootstrap'; java.math.BigDecimal is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Suppose, the proxy simply implemented the same interfaces (in this case, `Comparable` since it's the only interface implemented by `BigDecimal`). I tried to fool it:

```java
    public static BigDecimal getScaleObliviousProxy(BigDecimal scaleAwareBigDecimal) {
        return (BigDecimal) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                scaleAwareBigDecimal.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[0], // "You know what, it doesn't implement anything! Go extend"
                (proxy, method, args) -> {
```

but I got the same exception

How do I solve this problem? Is there any way to force it to use extension-based proxying, not interface-based one?

**P.S.:** Surely, I can do something like this

```java
    public static BigDecimal getScaleObliviousProxy(BigDecimal scaleAwareBigDecimal) {
        return new BigDecimal(scaleAwareBigDecimal.toString()) {
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
                return otherObject instanceof BigDecimal &&
                        areEqual(this, (BigDecimal) otherObject);
            }
        };
    }
```

but imagine I want to perform some runtime post-processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's proxies cannot extend a class, because they already extend `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. They can only implement interfaces, so you'll never be able to get a `BigDecimal` instance, only a `Comparable`. If you need more capabilities, you have to look into ByteBuddy, CGLib (this is what Spring uses when it has to proxy concrete classes, but it's barely maintained these days) or similars libs, they can produce what you're after.

Here's one way to do it using ByteBuddy (note that I'm not exactly familiar with ByteBuddy, so I may have done something wrong):

```java
public class Test {

    //No need to generate a new class for each proxy instance
    private static final Class<? extends BigDecimal> PROXY_TYPE = generateProxy();

    private static Class<? extends BigDecimal> generateProxy() {
        return new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(BigDecimal.class)
                .method(ElementMatchers.isEquals())
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class))
                .make()
                .load(Test.class.getClassLoader()) //BigDecimal classloader won't know where to find Interceptor.class
                .getLoaded();
    }

    public static class Interceptor {
        @RuntimeType
        public static boolean intercept(@This BigDecimal _this, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            Object that = args[0];
            return that instanceof BigDecimal && _this.compareTo((BigDecimal) that) == 0;
        }
    }

    public static BigDecimal getScaleObliviousProxy(BigDecimal scaleAwareBigDecimal) {
        try {
            return PROXY_TYPE.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(scaleAwareBigDecimal.toString());
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomBigDecimal() {
        BigDecimal ten = BigDecimal.TEN;
        BigDecimal x = getScaleObliviousProxy(new BigDecimal("10.0"));
        assertTrue(x.equals(ten));
    }
}
```